# Async.until function parameters

Tags: node.js

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) { //This is the first task, and callback is its callback task
        db.save('xxx', 'a', function(err) {
            //Now we have saved to the DB, so let's tell async that this task is done
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback) { //This is the second task, and callback is its callback task
        db.save('xxx', 'b', callback); //Since we don't do anything interesting in db.save()'s callback, we might as well just pass in the task callback 
    }
], function(err) { //This is the final callback
    console.log('Both a and b are saved now');
});
```

Hey I found this code online when I trying to understand async in node.js and my question I have with the code above is in the array of functions in async.parallel, what is the callback parameter that is passed in each function? Where does that callback parameter come from and what is the purpose of that variable? I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but I can't grasp a solid understanding of this callback's...

Comment: Did any of these answers answer your question?  If so, you can indicate to the community which one was the best answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will also earn both you and the person who wrote the answer some reputation points which can lead to more privileges on this site.

Comment: I tried looking for the green checkmark but for some reason I am not able to see it under the up vote button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract that `async.parallel()` defines is that you pass it an array of functions.  It will then call each of those functions and pass those function a single argument that is a function reference (I think of it as a completion callback).  For `async.parallel()` to work properly, your function that you pass in the array has to call that function reference when your async operation is done.  When it calls that function reference, it can pass an error argument and a result argument.  If the error argument is truthy, then it will stop further processing and feed that error back to the calling code.

The function that async passes a reference to is internal to the async library and when you call it, the async library does some housekeeping to keep track of how many asynchronous operations are still going, whether they're all done now, whether further processing should stop due to error, etc...

You can essentially think of it like the async library completion function.  When your asynchronous operation is done, you have to call that completion function so that the async library knows that your operation is now done.  That's how it is able to manage and keep track of your multiple async operations.  If you don't call that completion callback, then the async library never knows when your asynchronous operation is done.

Comment: OH ok that makes sense now. The thing I am still confused on is async.parallel runs in parallel, so it can complete any of the given functions in the array in any order correct? Do is that callback used to say that a function has been completed in the array of functions that was passed?

Comment: @ClayHorder - `async.parallel()` initially starts all your async operations.  Then, as each one completes, they each call their own async callback to tell async that they're done.  When they've all finished, then async will call your callback to notify you that they are all done now.  The order that the functions finish depend entirely upon what they are doing and how long each operation takes to finish.  Their is no predictable finish order when using `.parallel()`, but it will collect the results in order for you.

Comment: Oh ok... Thank you so much! The concept it now clear to me!

Answer (score 0):

The callback parameter is a function created by async. When you call it in each of the array functions, it signals async that the function completed. In that way, you can control when your function is done - when you call callback.

When callback is called from all the array functions, the final function is called.

Comment: So the callback() method in the first function in the array of function's, what function is that callback() referring to?

Comment: Its the function passed in to the first function in the array. Its defined in the async code and passed in to your functions. A lot of async code works that way...when you call something asynchronous, a callback can help your code finish where it left off before starting the asynchronous call. I imagine the callbacks for your functions basically check to see if all callbacks were called yet, if they were, call the final function, otherwise, mark the current function as called and not call the final function until a subsequent callback finds all functions were called.

Comment: Ok, so is that callback() line calling another function somewhere? Or is its purpose just to say that the function is completed? Because I am a little confused by the name, callback implies that it will callback to something but I don't understand if another function somewhere is being called back or is callback just used to signify that the function is over.